# GNUplot stacked multiplot - Top plot does not align perfectly

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make a stacked plot with GNUplot.

```
TMARGIN = 0.05
BMARGIN = 0.15
LMARGIN = 0.15
RMARGIN = 0.0

TCOORD=1-TMARGIN
BCOORD=1-BMARGIN

DY = 0.2

# Ratio
set size ratio 0.5

# Tics
unset xtics
unset ytics

# Multiplot
set multiplot layout 4, 1
unset key
unset title

# Global
set lmargin at screen LMARGIN
set rmargin at screen RMARGIN

# Plot 0
set tmargin at screen TCOORD; set bmargin at screen TCOORD-DY;
plot sin(x)

# Plot 1
set tmargin at screen TCOORD-DY; set bmargin at screen TCOORD-(2*DY)
plot sin(x)

# Plot 2
set tmargin at screen TCOORD-(2*DY); set bmargin at screen TCOORD-(3*DY)
plot sin(x)

# Plot 3
set tmargin at screen TCOORD-(3*DY); set bmargin at screen TCOORD-(4*DY)
set xlabel "xlabel"
plot sin(x)
```

With the script above I end up with the top plot not aligned to the others.

[image]

Out of ideas.
Grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: This is "Version 5.4 patchlevel 2" on Archlinux if relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tries to use three different methods to adjust the plot positions: `set ratio`, `set multiplot layout`, and `set margin`.  They are fighting each other. If I understand the intent correctly, this can all be done in the `multiplot layout` command.   If the 2:1 ratio is important, you may have to calculate the right margin manually and/or adjust the width of the output using the `size` parameter of `set term`.

```
# No extra stuff around the edges
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
unset title

# Multiplot
set multiplot layout 4, 1 margins screen 0.15, 1.0, 0.1, 1.0 spacing 0,0

# Plot 0
plot sin(x)

# Plot 1
plot sin(x)

# Plot 2
plot sin(x)

# Plot 3
set xlabel "xlabel"
plot sin(x)

unset multi
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help.
Works like a charm.